# Login Disappears, Can't Reach TTY

Tags: boot, uefi, login

Using a desktop computer. It's been working fine, but then I updated Ubuntu, and after restart I'm seeing problems. After booting, I see a login screen, which sometimes has a login window and sometimes doesn't. Regardless, no keystrokes are showing up in the GUI. The mouse cursor moves, but I can't click anything. I have tried `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1` and all the other function keys `F2` - `F12`, with and without `FN`, but no command line interface appears.

I can get into the BIOS by pressing `esc` during boot, and the most promising looking option is "Launch EFI Shell from filesystem device" but it tells me "WARNING Not Found."

Any ideas?

The BIOS is American Megatrends, Inc. I can boot from it but just puts me back into a dead end since I can't bring up a command line interface.

**Possibly irrelevant update:** there is a very short window of opportunity in which I can press `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F3` and bring up a non-GUI screen, but it endlessly scrolls text very quickly. I could only read it by taking a video and slowing it down. I'm seeing lots of hard to understand stuff but this doesn't sound good

"Comm: (python3) Tainted: P" and
"Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#21 stuck for 22s!"

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove that custom DE and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Are you saying I should remove hardware from the machine, or something else?

Comment: No you said someone made a custom desktop environment (DE) and you are using that. I said remove that first it may be the issue. Go back to a supported DE.

Comment: If the login is showing on tty1 it is NOT a video card driver problem :)  I agree with David: it is likely connected to the custom DE.

Comment: I see, just bad terminology on my part. By "custom desktop" I mean a desktop computer that was custom built. I will edit.